# Google Sheets App Script Pulling Three to Push Results

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm currently working on a stock portfolio manager for myself on Google Sheets. I know that they base their language on JavaScript, which I know very little of.

My code is supposed to pull the tickers, values, and action. With this information, it will see if the action is marked as either "Dividend", "Sell", or "Withdrawl" and if it arent it will check if tickers is "cash" If not it will proceed to add up all the values of shares per stock.

```
function MyPortfolio(tickers, values, action) {

var total = []
var sums = {}

for (i = 0; i < tickers.length; i++){
    var t = tickers[i].toString()

for (a = 0; a < action.length; a++){
  var ac = action[a].toString()

  if(ac != "Dividend" || ac != "Sell" || ac != "Withdrawl"){
      if(t != "Cash"){
        if(t in sums){
          sums[t] += Number(values[i])
        } 
        else {
          sums[t] = Number(values[i])
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


for(var ticker in sums){
    if (sums[ticker]>0){
      total.push([ticker, sums[ticker]])
    }
  }
  return total
}
```

I've attached a screenshot of the information that the code is supposed to pull stuff from.
[image]

And this is what I put into the cell: `=MyPortfolio('Dividend/Portfolio Recording'!O7:Q1026,'Dividend/Portfolio Recording'!U7:X1026,'Dividend/Portfolio Recording'!R7:T1026)`

and if the symbol is not "Cash" or the Actions are not "Dividend", "Sell", or "Withdrawl" it should push everything else to my dashboard but I keep getting an error.
[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the details of your current issue of your script? And, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? Or, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: You are referencing Columns O:Q instead of O, R:T instead of R, and U:X instead of X. Try: `=MyPortfolio('Dividend/Portfolio Recording'!O7:O1026,'Dividend/Portfolio Recording'!U7:U1026,'Dividend/Portfolio Recording'!R7:R1026)`  This should return a single column of values in each case instead of 3 Column arrays.